# Python vs IronPython for BitCoin Development

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, ironpython, bitcoin

Been looking at porting a BitCoin Mining Pool server across to IronPython

Apart from the limitations of Ironpython supporting upto Python ~v2.7

Is a Ironpython/windows platform really not suited to this type of high volume/large transactional system

What are some of the other limitations I might encounter or should i juts bite the bullet and build up an ubuntu programming RIG

If the later what would be an easy IDE for someone coming from a c# Visual Studio world

Thanks in Adavnce

Comment: As long as you don't use any .NET features, you can write code that works in both CPython and IronPython, meaning you can debug it in Visual Studio under IronPython, then maybe do a sanity check with native Windows CPython and/or Cygwin CPython, then test on the linux box. Plus, even if you can't use IronPython (e.g., because you need one of the tiny handful of features that hasn't been ported), you can still use VS as an editor/IDE.

Comment: Also, when you say "port", do you mean "make some hopefully minor changes" or "rewrite the networking core to use a different API, likely even a different _kind_ of API"? For that matter, how is the current Python server implemented? Twisted, Django, a CGI running behind a webserver, …?

Comment: Making Minor changes..The core app as a v0.9 works...I think I have read Twisted...it is running Python3+

Comment: For my dev VS should be good to go as outlined...When problems occur in a Prod Linux environment and have difficulty on getting REPO of the error in dev. What IDE would you use the prod box

Comment: I wouldn't use an IDE on the production box. The ability to do live source-level debugging is rarely useful on servers, and firing up, say, Eclipse on your production box is a good way to knock your throughput way down, even if you _don't_ try to interfere with the running service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your existing code is built, or how you intend the new version to work, it's hard to answer specifically, but I can give some generalities.

IronPython limitations/issues, in decreasing order of importance:
 * No third-party C extension modules. If you depend on any, you'll have to find a .NET equivalent or reimplement the same thing yourself. If not, not a problem.
 * No 3.x. If you know 3.x, Unicode is a lot easier, `yield from` rocks, etc., and 3.x keeps improving (and even speeding up), while 2.x is stagnant. But how much this is worth is a matter of personal preference, not something anyone else can give you an objective answer on.
 * No third-party pure Python modules that rely (in important ways) on refcounting semantics. There aren't too many of these out there, but if you need one, you need it.
 * There are a handful of differences between IronPython and CPython, listed in the release notes. Probably none of these will affect you, but you should check.
 * If there's any heavy application logic (as opposed to all of the work being networking/files/database), IronPython is much faster than CPython at a few things and much slower at a few others, so you probably need to profile and perf-test before you go too far down either path. (And consider at least PyPy, if not Jython, while you're at it…) But usually this isn't an issue for servers.

Next, is a Windows platform suited to a high-volume systems? Windows is definitely capable of handling thousands of connections per second (or requests, or bytes, or whatever's most relevant to your use case). It will probably never beat linux in pure connections/second/$, but you have to realistically trade off operational costs vs. dev costs. However, oversimplifying a bit, Windows sucks at reactors and rocks at proactors, while linux rocks at reactors and is decent at proactors (and there are other similar issues—e.g., substitute processes/threads for the above). So, even though Windows *can* do nearly as well as linux in general, it can't do as well *on the same code*, or often even the same designs. You need to architect your code to take advantage of Windows features and take into account Windows weaknesses. And if you're using a framework to do the heavy lifting for you, there are going to be fewer choices, and the best ones may not work like what you're used to, which is usually a much higher dev cost than changing platforms.

If you do go with CPython on linux, what IDE should you use? Stick with Visual Studio. You can, and probably should, write either all or most of your code in a cross-platform way that runs on both IronPython and linux CPython. Then you can code, test, and debug with Iron Python in Visual Studio, use native Windows CPython and/or Cygwin CPython for occasional sanity checks, and only touch linux for performance tests, final acceptance tests before releases, and debugging problems you can't repro on Windows. You'll still occasionally need a simple text editor on linux, but IDLE, or whichever of vi-vs.-emacs you prefer, or whichever GUI text editor your linux distro comes with as the default will be fine.

If your application logic is tightly coupled with your reactor design or something, this could be difficult. If it's doable, it's probably worth doing, but if it's not… well, you can *still* use Visual Studio as an editor and project organizer, even if the actual code is intended to be run on a linux box. You don't get the nifty debugger integration, etc. that way, but you still get a lot of mileage.

Comment: Thanks Dude need to have my ducks in a row before I start the journey :D